# Trying to append a List to a List on AWS DynamoDB with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to code the module to create a new task in my todoList using Node.js and DynamoDB, but I can't figure out the right structure for the new task I'm appending.

So far, I have this code for updating the list:

```
const { petID, newTask } = req.body

const newTasks = [{S: newTask , BOOL: false}]

const paramsUpdate = {
      TableName: 'PetBuddyToDoLists',
      Key: {
        PetID: petID,
      },
      UpdateExpression: 'SET ToDoList = list_append(ToDoList, :newTask)',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':newTask':  newTasks,
      },
      ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
    };

dynamoDB.update(paramsUpdate, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error updating list items:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error updating list items.' });
        return;
      }
      console.log('Item created successfully.', data);
      res.status(201).json({ message: 'Item created successfully.' });
    });
```

The initial structure in the DB is as follows:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "toDoList": [
        {
            "L": [
                {
                    "S": "Task 1"
                },
                {
                    "BOOL": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when I make a POST request with the new item:

```
{
    "petID": "the_pet_id",
    "newTask": "Task 2"
}
```

I receive a response indicating that the item was added successfully. But when I perform a GET request on the DB again, I notice that I get this unexpected structure:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "toDoList": [
        {
            "L": [
                {
                    "S": "Task 1"
                },
                {
                    "BOOL": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "M": {
                "BOOL": {
                    "BOOL": false
                },
                "S": {
                    "S": "Task 2"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone help? It's not adding to the same structure as "Task 1," and it's causing issues with my frontend.

This is my first post, so I apologize for any mistakes I may have made!

I Pretend that the structure when adding new task it will get like this

```
{
    "success": true,
    "toDoList": [
        {
            "L": [
                {
                    "S": "Task 1"
                },
                {
                    "BOOL": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "L": [
                {
                    "S": "Task 2"
                },
                {
                    "BOOL": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Good first post. But you forgot to add one crucial detail: what is the value of `newTasks`?

Comment: Oh my bad! I just edited the post with, wich I hope, all the crucial code.

const { petID, newTask } = req.body

const newTasks = [{S: newTask , BOOL: false}]


Thanks a lot @LeeroyHannigan!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumption here that I believe you are using a high level client and low level parameters.

Have a view of this blog:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/exploring-amazon-dynamodb-sdk-clients/

Try concert your new tasks to this:

```
const newTasks = [{ newTask , BOOL: false}]
```